# Find whether a sentence has the starting words of another sentence or the ending words of the same sentence

Tags: python

For example , I have a set of sentences like this :

```
New York is in New York State
D.C. is the capital of United States
The weather is cool in the south of that country.
Lets take a bus to get to point b from point a.
```

And another sentence like this :

```
is cool in the south of that country
```

The output should be : `The weather is cool in the south of that country.`

If I have an input like `of United States The weather is cool` the output should be :

```
D.C. is the capital of United States The weather is cool in the south of that country.
```

So far i tried `difflib` and got the overlap but that doesn't quite solve the problem in all cases.

Comment: the question is unclear, but I will add that you can easily find if a substring pattern is included in a string using `in`. For example, `"is cool in the south of that country" in "The weather is cool in the south of that country."` will return `True`.

Comment: It would help to see what you tried, and which cases it didn't solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a dictionary of starting expressions and ending expressions from the sentences.  Then find a prefix and suffix for the sentence to extend in these dictionaries.  In both cases you would need to build/check one key for each substring of words starting from the beginning and from the end:

```
sentences="""New York is in New York State
D.C. is the capital of United States
The weather is cool in the south of that country
Lets take a bus to get to point b from point a""".split("\n")

ends   =  { tuple(sWords[i:]):sWords[:i] for s in sentences
               for sWords in [s.split()] for i in range(len(sWords)) }
starts  = { tuple(sWords[:i]):sWords[i:] for s in sentences
               for sWords in [s.split()] for i in range(1,len(sWords)+1) }

def extendSentence(sentence):
    sWords   = sentence.split(" ")
    prefix   = next( (ends[p] for i in range(1,len(sWords)+1)
                      for p in [tuple(sWords[:i])] if p in ends),
                    [])
    suffix   = next( (starts[p] for i in range(len(sWords))
                      for p in [tuple(sWords[i:])] if p in starts),
                    [])  
    return " ".join(prefix + [sentence] + suffix)
```

output:

```
print(extendSentence("of United States The weather is cool"))

# D.C. is the capital of United States The weather is cool in the south of that country

print(extendSentence("is cool in the south of that country"))

# The weather is cool in the south of that country
```

*note that I had to remove the periods at the end of sentences because they prevent matching. You will need to clean these up in the dictionary building step*